# Regular expression to match "item" followed by two digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that would split strings like itemXY where X and Y are integer (item23) to be used in javascript.

I would like it to return the integers x and y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are always going to have two digits, use this:

```
var item = "item24";
var result = item.match(/(\d)(\d)$/);
var digit1 = result[1];
var digit2 = result[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to bother the regex parser with this problem.  If the first part of the string up to the number is always the same length, you can use [*slice()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [*substring()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
var str = "item23";

alert(str.slice(4));
//-> 23
```

This would be faster and less complicated than a regular expression.  If you need the numbers to be separated, you can just split them:

```
var arr = str.slice(4).split();
//-> ["2", "3"]
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know about this method. Will try it out sometime... :)

Comment: @Shouvik: In my experience it's always better to avoid using regular expressions if there's a more suitable method available.  I've updated my answer to include a solution that would give the same result as your accepted answer.

Comment: Assuming the text is always 4 characters long.

Comment: @Bennor: or if the number at the end is always 2 digits long (which your answer also assumes), you could use `-2` instead of `4`.

Comment: Agreed. I've actually upvoted this answer as I think it's better to use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need are last digits then:

```
\d+$
```

will do the work. `\d+` means 1 or more digits, and `$` means "at end". Then you can use `result_string[0]` and `result_string[1]` (of course you should check length):

```
var txt = "item25";
var result = txt.match(/\d+$/);
if (result != null)
    {
    var digits = result[0];
    alert(digits[0]);
    alert(digits[1]);
    }
```

You can also use regex groups like:

```
(\d)(\d)$
```

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to extrac "23" to a variable?

here you are:

```
/^item([0-9]+)$/
```

will extract any number from itemXXXXXX returning that number.

Comment: yeah I will be extracting the number to a variable and then concatenate it to another string